# How can I add custom reactions to a bot message without the reaction being on the server?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to be able to add a custom reaction to my bots message it just posted.  That part I know how to do.  What I don't know though is if there is even a way for a bot to use it's own custom reactions that don't already exist on the server.  I can give the bots any perms that it needs.

Just need to know if there is a way to add reactions to the server via the bot and if so how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible!

First I would recommand to upload this emote on your server so it is definitly existing.

Then the Syntax would be like:

```
.setEmoji("<:[name of the emote how you would use it on your server]:[unique emote ID]>")
```

This will only work if your bot is added to the server with "Allow custom emotes" and can also be restricted in the channel by the other server.

To get the custom emote ID on your server simply type a Backslash `\` in your server and add the emote behind an it will get resolved.

Example:

```
.setEmoji("<:gcalt:1122610718559182978>")
```

[image: Emote resolve]

Comment: So are you saying I first need to add it to my discord server, then I can have the bot auto add the emoji when it joins a new server?  Is there not a way with discord.js to specify a local file path and have it upload an image to the discord server it's currently on then add it with something like the setEmoji command?